# Hello , i m trying to run my app but it shows your cocapods is currupted

Tags: flutter, dart, rubygems, cocoapods, homebrew

maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % sudo gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.

when i tried to run my app it shows

Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping pod install.
You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (6.1.7.3)
addressable (2.8.4)
algoliasearch (1.27.5)
atomos (0.1.3)
CFPropertyList (2.3.6)
claide (1.1.0)
cocoapods (1.12.1, 1.11.3)
cocoapods-core (1.12.1)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.5)
cocoapods-downloader (1.6.3)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.1)
cocoapods-trunk (1.6.0)
cocoapods-try (1.2.0)
colored2 (3.1.2)
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2)
escape (0.0.4)
ethon (0.16.0)
ffi (1.15.5)
fourflusher (2.3.1)
fuzzy_match (2.0.4)
gh_inspector (1.1.3)
httpclient (2.8.3)
i18n (1.14.1)
json (2.6.3)
libxml-ruby (3.2.1)
mini_portile2 (2.8.0)
minitest (5.18.0)
molinillo (0.8.0)
mygem (0.0.1)
nanaimo (0.3.0)
nap (1.1.0)
netrc (0.11.0)
nokogiri (1.13.8)
public_suffix (4.0.7)
rexml (3.2.5)
ruby-macho (2.5.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.13)
typhoeus (1.4.0)
tzinfo (2.0.6)
xcodeproj (1.22.0)
zeitwerk (2.6.8)

these are gems in my mac(intell chip) i idk shoud i have to delete them all or not

i tried thise things
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % gem install cocoapods

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/”YOUR USER FORLDER”/.zprofile

zsh: permission denied: /Users/”YOUR
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % brew install cocoapods

zsh: command not found: brew
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % gem install cocoapods

Successfully installed cocoapods-1.12.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.12.1
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % brew install chruby ruby-install
zsh: command not found: brew
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % brew install cocoapods

zsh: command not found: brew
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % gem install cocoapods

Successfully installed cocoapods-1.12.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.12.1
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % sudo gem uninstall cocoapods && sudo gem install cocoapods
Gem 'cocoapods' is not installed
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % flutter clean
Cleaning Xcode workspace...                                         5.3s
Cleaning Xcode workspace...                                         5.8s
Deleting build...                                                   32ms
Deleting .dart_tool...                                              26ms
Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                       0ms
Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                            0ms
Deleting ephemeral...                                                0ms
Deleting ephemeral...                                                1ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins-dependencies...                            0ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins...                                         1ms
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies... (1.0s)
audio_video_progress_bar 0.10.0 (1.0.1 available)
audioplayers 1.2.0 (4.1.0 available)
audioplayers_android 1.1.3 (3.0.2 available)
audioplayers_darwin 1.0.4 (4.1.0 available)
audioplayers_linux 1.0.2 (2.1.0 available)
audioplayers_platform_interface 2.1.0 (5.0.1 available)
audioplayers_web 2.1.0 (3.1.0 available)
audioplayers_windows 1.1.1 (2.0.2 available)
cli_util 0.3.5 (0.4.0 available)
collection 1.17.1 (1.17.2 available)
dio 4.0.6 (5.2.1+1 available)
file 6.1.4 (7.0.0 available)
flutter_launcher_icons 0.10.0 (0.13.1 available)
flutter_native_splash 2.2.16 (2.3.1 available)
flutter_svg 1.1.6 (2.0.7 available)
http 0.13.6 (1.0.0 available)
image 3.3.0 (4.0.17 available)
lottie 1.4.3 (2.4.0 available)
matcher 0.12.15 (0.12.16 available)
material_color_utilities 0.2.0 (0.6.0 available)
source_span 1.9.1 (1.10.0 available)
test_api 0.5.1 (0.6.0 available)
Got dependencies!
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (6.1.7.3)
addressable (2.8.4)
algoliasearch (1.27.5)
atomos (0.1.3)
CFPropertyList (2.3.6)
claide (1.1.0)
cocoapods (1.12.1, 1.11.3)
cocoapods-core (1.12.1)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.5)
cocoapods-downloader (1.6.3)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.1)
cocoapods-trunk (1.6.0)
cocoapods-try (1.2.0)
colored2 (3.1.2)
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2)
escape (0.0.4)
ethon (0.16.0)
ffi (1.15.5)
fourflusher (2.3.1)
fuzzy_match (2.0.4)
gh_inspector (1.1.3)
httpclient (2.8.3)
i18n (1.14.1)
json (2.6.3)
libxml-ruby (3.2.1)
mini_portile2 (2.8.0)
minitest (5.18.0)
molinillo (0.8.0)
mygem (0.0.1)
nanaimo (0.3.0)
nap (1.1.0)
netrc (0.11.0)
nokogiri (1.13.8)
public_suffix (4.0.7)
rexml (3.2.5)
ruby-macho (2.5.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.13)
typhoeus (1.4.0)
tzinfo (2.0.6)
xcodeproj (1.22.0)
zeitwerk (2.6.8)
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % sudo gem uninstall
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
Gem 'cocoapods' is not installed
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
Gem 'cocoapods' is not installed
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % sudo gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
maulikkoladiya@MacBook-Pro pokedex-master % pod install
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

but it didnt worked at all . so, does anyone knows how to deal with this ?
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `the CocoaPods is installed but broken. Try reinstalling the CocoaPods`.

Run the following command to uninstall and install the CocoaPods.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods && sudo gem install cocoapods
```

For the `Gem` issue you are getting, try updating the ruby file

```
brew update
brew install ruby
```

Comment: hey there , i tried this one also it says      Gem 'cocoapods' is not installed
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.

Comment: try `brew update` before that command

Comment: it's not gem issue i m getting about . its issue about  You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory. i m gatting the same problem with the gem installation also